# Does a derived class have a default constructor from base class?

Tags: c++

I have a class B that is derived from A (B : A).

B only have some additional member variables. I want to be able construct a B object out of a A object by simply copying the inherited variables from the A object. The B-specific member variables could be left as junk. No need to call the inherited variables' copy constructor, a bit by bit copy is enough for me (as they are integer types).

Does the compiler provide such constructor or should I write it myself ?

Comment: Write it yourself (`B(A a): A(a) {}`)

Comment: You can do `using A::A;` in `B`, that has some pitfalls

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can use the constructor of base class in derived class either creating the constructor of derived class or if u are not creating constructor of derive class when you create its object the constructor of base classnis automatically called